# tabularray: Reading a table stored in a macro by catchfile

Tags: tables, macros, catchfile, tabularray

How to fix the following error, so that the table saved in `\MyTable` can be read by `tabularray`?

> ./tabularrayfilecatch.tex:29: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
> \MyTable ->1 &
> 2 \ 3 & 4 \ 5 & 6 \ 7 & 8 \ 9 & 10 \ 11 & 12 \ 13 & 14 ... l.29  \end
> {tblr}

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
    1  &   2  \\
    3  &   4  \\
    5  &   6  \\
    7  &   8  \\
    9  &  10  \\
    11  &  12  \\
    13  &  14  \\
    15  &  16  \\
    17  &  18  \\
    19  &  20  \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=75mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, catchfile}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
    
    \CatchFileDef{\MyTable}{mytable.tex}{}
    
    \begin{tblr}[ long ]{ colspec = {X S} }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        One & {{{Two}}}  \\
        \midrule
        \MyTable
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `catchfile` has no role here. Also `\newcommand{\MyTable}{1\\2}` would result in an error. The documentation says to use `\NewTableCommand{\MyTable}{...}`, but it fails as well.

Comment: @egreg `\NewTableCommand` is for defining commands which only change the styles of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 2021M (2021-08-01) of `tabularray` package, you can use `expand` option to expand every occurrence of a specified macro once:

```
\begin{longtblr}[expand=\MyTable]{ colspec = {X S} }
     \toprule[1.5pt]
        One & {{{Two}}}  \\
     \midrule
        \MyTable
     \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{longtblr}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `tblr` wants to see `\MyTable` expanded (in order to *see* the `&` tabs and `\\` linebreaks).  So I save the introduction of the `tblr` environment in `\tmp` and then `\expandafter\tmp\MyTable...`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
    1  &   2  \\
    3  &   4  \\
    5  &   6  \\
    7  &   8  \\
    9  &  10  \\
    11  &  12  \\
    13  &  14  \\
    15  &  16  \\
    17  &  18  \\
    19  &  20  \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=75mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, catchfile}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
    
    \CatchFileDef{\MyTable}{mytable.tex}{}
    
    \def\tmp{\begin{tblr}[ long ]{ colspec = {X S} }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        One & {{{Two}}}  \\
        \midrule}
        \expandafter\tmp\MyTable
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As Steven B. Segletes already said:

The `tblr`-environment wants to "see" `\MyTable` expanded.

You can achieve this as shown by Steven B. Segletes via temporary macros.

Another approach is having two macro-arguments and expanding the first macro-argument before exchanging it with the second one:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
    1  &   2  \\
    3  &   4  \\
    5  &   6  \\
    7  &   8  \\
    9  &  10  \\
    11  &  12  \\
    13  &  14  \\
    15  &  16  \\
    17  &  18  \\
    19  &  20  \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=75mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, catchfile}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}

\begin{document}
    
    \CatchFileDef{\MyTable}{mytable.tex}{}
    
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\MyTable}{%
    \begin{tblr}[ long ]{ colspec = {X S} }%
        \toprule[1.5pt]%
        One & {{{Two}}}  \\%
        \midrule
   }%
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]